# "Tag start is not closed" when using Handlebars.js

Tags: html, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm getting an error that says "Tag start is not closed" in the following HTML code after the input tag. I can't seem to figure out why since I am using the Handlebars syntax properly. Can someone help me out please?:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="todo">
    </div>
    <script id="item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        // Your code goes here
        <div>
            <input id="todo-complete" type="checkbox" {{#if completed}} "checked" {{/if}}>
            <label>{{title}}</label>
        </div>
    </script>


    <script src= "underscore.js"> </script>
    <script src="handlebars-v1.3.0.js"> </script>
    <script src="backbone.js"> </script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"> </script>
    <script src="main.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm using Jetbrain's Webstorm IDE. It's giving me an error saying that "Tag start is not closed" for the input tag...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You IDE doesn't understand Handlebars syntax, hence reporting a Error, which you should ignore.